# Why is my Golang code of LeetCode's Increasing Subsequence TLE?

Tags: c++, algorithm, go

The problem is on LeetCode:

> 491. Increasing Subsequences
>
> Given an integer array, your task is to find all the different possible increasing subsequences of the given array, and the length of an increasing subsequence should be at least 2.
>
> Example:
>
> Input: [4, 6, 7, 7]
>
> Output: [[4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 6, 7], [4, 6, 7, 7], [6, 7], [6, 7, 7], [7,7], [4,7,7]]

I have wrote the same algorithm in C++ and Golang respectively.

The Golang version keeps getting TLE on the case [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]. But the C++ version worked well and beat 72% cpp solutions.

I had a hard time trying to find out what's wrong with the Golang version, so I really appreciate your help.

Here are my codes:

Golang:

```
func findSubsequences(nums []int) [][]int {

    n := len(nums)
    m := make(map[int]int)
    cur := make([][]int, 1)
    cur[0] = []int{}

    var ans [][]int
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        lim := len(cur)

        st, ok := m[nums[i]]
        if !ok {
            st = 0
        }

        m[nums[i]] = lim

        for j := st; j < lim; j++ {
            if len(cur[j]) > 0 && nums[i] < cur[j][len(cur[j])-1] {
                continue
            }

            tmp := append(cur[j], nums[i])
            cur = append(cur, tmp)

            if len(tmp) >= 2 {
                ans = append(ans, tmp)
            }
        }
    }

    return ans
}
```

C++:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> findSubsequences(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> ans, cur;
        cur.push_back(vector<int>());

        unordered_map<int, int> m;

        int n = nums.size(), st;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (m.count(nums[i]))
                st = m[nums[i]];
            else 
                st = 0;

            int lim = cur.size();
            m[nums[i]] = lim;
            for (int j = st; j < lim; j++) {
                if (cur[j].size() > 0 && nums[i] < cur[j].back())
                    continue;

                cur.push_back(cur[j]);
                cur.back().push_back(nums[i]);

                if (cur.back().size() >= 2)
                    ans.push_back(cur.back());
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: I think the algorithm is to heavy in both cases in Go and in C++ both. You are using vectors an hash tables, when they can be avoided. But C++ compiler able to optimize vector and unordered map, when Go can not.

Comment: @VictorGubin Hi, sorry I don't see where the vectors can be replaced by  hash maps. I think the arrays need to stay in order to avoid generating repeat subsequences.

Comment: I mean, C++ able to optimize vector and unordered_map classes, since they are compile time templates. i.e. member functions can be inline, calls to operator new can be changed to stack memory allocations etc. I don't think Go lang can do it with their standard library. If you really need a benchmark try use only raw language data-structures like arrays. 2. See [bench marking](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=go&lang2=gpp). In some cases Go able to win, however in most cases C++ is better choose.

Comment: @VictorGubin I see what you mean now. Thank you very much for your help.